# An item with the same key has already been added - Visual Studio Stops Responding

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, visual-studio-2019

I work on **Visual Studio 2019**, i created a C# WPF Project and i used devexpress for WPF,
When i set the **DataSource** of **any control** that takes a DataSource like (GridControl, Chart, Diagram, TreeView...), I'm getting this error:

**An item with the same key has already been added**.

Then visual studio are **freezing**, and can't continue working until i **end the process** from the **task manager**.

**NB:** The problem persist in the same project only, when i create a new project, the problem disappears, so basically the problem occurs in my project.

Does anyone faced the same problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set a primary key and are all of them unique in your database?

Comment: I don't think he is concerned about the key being a duplicate, I think the question is why is VS 2019 freezing?

Comment: Hi @nilsK, i did not achieve this step yet. The problem occurs directly when i hit the **Item Source Wizard** Button.

Comment: Hi @MortenBork yea exactly, and i should set the data source normally and not getting this error!

Comment: @ZiadMansour I don't intend to bash anyones product, so I will keep my judgement out of the comment here, but I would say, bugs happen. 
I think this is a combination of choice addons, and VS perhaps not handling something entirely in an intended way. Or that the plugin, isn't working entirely as intended with VS 2019. 

Have you tried a different IDE? Maybe Rider or Visual Studio Code? 

I don't say you have to change. But VS has a reputation for not being the most well performing IDE especially with plugins/addons.

I can't tell you why VS freezes.

Comment: @ZiadMansour However the exception causing it is claiming you are adding the same primary key into a dictionary or a collection with a unique constraint on a key. 

You would have to investigate specifically in your code, where this mapping happens and reconfigure, or alter your data to adhere to this requirement.
If the Exception doesn't occur, the freeze can't happen.

Comment: I think that error is about a duplicate name of something. Being used as the key in a dictionary. Duplicate column names can give a similar problem in ssrs. Or maybe internally there's a default datasource name and you already used that in your problem project.